# How to get CType/DirectCast working with a defined variable instead of a direct type?

Tags: vb.net

I can't get the code below working.

The error is in the last line: Type 'ChangeType' is not defined.

Does the compiler thinks that ChangeType is a customtype which i did't have defiened ?

I have no clue, plz give me a hint.
May be I can't see the forest for the trees.

```
Dim DataValue as String = "True"
Dim ChangeTypeIndex() As String = {"System.Boolean", "System.Char", "System.SByte", "System.Byte", "System.Int16"}
Dim ChangeType As Type = Type.GetType(ChangeTypeIndex(0))
Dim Result = DirectCast(DataValue, ChangeType)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? DataValue is already string, it seems you have no need to cast it to anything?

Comment: I'm failing to understand the purpose of this even if you get it working. You're specifying a specific index of the array, so why not just use `Boolean.TryParse()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible in VB.NET.  VB.NET is a type-safe language, and the express purpose of `DirectCast` is to aid in the compile-time type checking.  Since it is analyzed for correctness at compile-time, it, by definition, can't be given a variable for the type.  `DirectCast` can only be used to cast an object to another directly-related type (by inheritance or implementation).  Since `DataValue` is a `String`, you couldn't cast it to a `Boolean` anyway (since `String` doesn't inherit from `Boolean`), even if `DirectCast` did allow you to pass a variable type like that.

.NET does support reflection and late-binding, so it is possible to do the same *kind* of thing, if you really need to, but it's generally a good idea to avoid these kinds of things as much as you can, so as to ensure that you are getting the most benefit out of the compiler's type-checking safety measures.

Warnings aside, if you really need to do this, a close approximation would be something like this:

```
Option Strict Off

' ...

Dim dataValue As String = "True"
Dim changeTypeIndex() As String = {"System.Boolean", "System.Char", "System.SByte", "System.Byte", "System.Int16"}
Dim changeType As Type = Type.GetType(changeTypeIndex(0))
Dim o As Object = Activator.CreateInstance(changeType)
Dim result As Object = o.Parse(dataValue)
Console.WriteLine(result.GetType().Name)  ' Outputs "Boolean"
Console.WriteLine(result)  ' Outputs "True"
```

Comment: Wow - an answer in lightspeed. Are you a real person or an AI system from outerspace?  :)  where to give you some credits ?

Comment: If you think this is the best answer, you can mark it as the answer, but since you are a new user with a low reputation score, I believe there is a time-based limit on that where you have to wait a certain period of time before it allows you to mark the correct answer.  Once you get enough reputation, not only will you be able to select the answer right away, but you'll also be able to give up-votes on as many answers as you want.

Comment: Ok, I think I have to declare my purpose in more detail. I wrote a program for acquiring data over different bus-system like M-Bus (Meter Bus), Rs 485/232, Dali, ModBus .... So I have to handle quite a lot of data of different types. I use DataTables to keep it handy. But i can only use one type for each column. So I decided to store all values as string & introduced another column to define the type. For any calculations I have to convert the values back to their origin type. So my proposed code snippet was for doing this. The fixed index of 0 was just for testing. Thx for your attention.

Comment: Does `o.Parse` really compile?  Since `o` is of type `Object` where does the `Parse` method come from?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Yes, when you have `Option Strict Off`, all `As Object` variables work like `dynamic` variables do in C#.  It's sort of the more readable shortcut so you don't have to use reflection to invoke a member.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Of course, turning option strict off has other implications too, so there can be unfortunate side effects, which is annoying.  Therefore, in VB, it's best to keep all your dynamic code in a partial class, or something, where option strict is only turned off for that one file, to keep the unsafety as localized as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but here is some code to play with.  Note that I have changed the 'types' in the array to contain valid type names.

```
    Dim DataValue As String = "True"
    Dim ChangeTypeIndex() As String = {"System.Boolean", "System.Char", "System.SByte", "System.Byte", "System.Int16"}
    Dim ChangeType As Type
    For x As Integer = 0 To ChangeTypeIndex.Length - 1
        ChangeType = Type.GetType(ChangeTypeIndex(x), True)
    Next
    ChangeType = Type.GetType(ChangeTypeIndex(0), True)
    Dim Result As Object = CTypeDynamic(DataValue, ChangeType)
```

Comment: Well, it's terrible, so I hate to say "Nice!", but, well, Nice!  I didn't know about `CTypeDynamic`.  That's clearly better than trusting the `Parse` method to be there, as in my answer.

Comment: @StevenDoggart - I guess thank you ;)  I also added the flag to Type.GetType to throw an error if the type is unknown.  Wish the OP would've be clearer in their intent.

Comment: I would suggest that the passed string argument be validated/converted for `String.Empty` or white-space to pass `Nothing` for conversion to the type's default value.  i.e. `CTypeDynamic(If(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DataValue), Nothing, DataValue), ChangeType)`